# Wix: If the app is running and uninstall the app is called then it doesn't give an option to close the application

Tags: wix, installation, bundle

If the application is running and user tries to uninstall the application then it doesn't give an option to close the application like it use to give for normal wix. This problem has occurred only after I moved to bundle project. Any step to be performed?
Earlier it use to give The following application should be closed before continuing the install:

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to look at:

1. If your bundle uninstalls the MSI product completely silently then the uninstall will obey that rule and will not offer any files-in-use dialogs.
2. Windows Installer sometimes decides not to force the user to shut down the app if it can be process isolated and cleaned up when the user finishes.

A verbose log will give more detail.

WiX has the CloseApp help for closing down apps, and integrating the app with Restart Manager can also help these situations.

Comment: Basically the plain wix behavior of asking:The following application should be closed before continuing the install: suits me the best. How can I acheive that?
 For @1: I think it is silent as it does show any UI of the MSI's getting uninstall.